# How can I get emailVerified from parse user in android?

Tags: android, parse-platform, boolean

I am confused; how do I get a boolean from parse.com USER database?
What I'm trying to achieve is :

```
if(The user who is trying to log in right now has not verified his email){
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Verify your email please",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

So, basically, my question is: How do I get a user's boolean value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can notice the "_User" class in Parse has a boolean column "emailVerified". You read the value of "emailVerified" as needed.

```
ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
Boolean isVerified = user.getBoolean("emailVerified");
```

Comment: I don't think you understand. How can I GET the boolean value?

Comment: @AbAppletic Did I answer your question ? If still you have a problem I will help you with a detailed code.